# how to integrate the newsstand in app

Tags: iphone

I would like to integrate new feature of iOS5 NEWSSTAND in my app. But i m get confused how to start. Can anybody help me ? is there any sample code for it ? can anybody know how to implement it in our app.
Thx

Comment: Read the docs ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StoreKit/Reference/NewsstandKit_Framework/_index.html ) and then ask specific questions about what you don't understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very nice tutorial for creating Apple NewsStand apps

http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial

Comment: its really a very helpful blog.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could start with the Apple documentation: [NewssstandKit Framework.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StoreKit/Reference/NewsstandKit_Framework/_index.html)