# subsrcibe the letter on newstand+iphone

Tags: iphone, newsstand-kit

I want to subscribe the letter or magazine in newsstand feature of iphone.
Can any one please help me..Is it possible to do that?If yes then please guide me..how to do it.Is there any url or sample code available in github or anywhere...please share it with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for how to integrate with Newsstand framework you can find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584061/how-to-integrate-the-newsstand-in-app/9662228#9662228)

Comment: thanks for hte reply..i get this link http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-how-to-make-your-app-work-with-the-newsstand/ but i cannot able to find or download that Urban Airship is it free or paid?

Comment: Paid. Check out http://urbanairship.com/pricing/ Use them if you don't  want to have your own server or (no in house web expertise or your server is not scalable etc)